# Issues when combining Spring Roo with JSF 2.0 + Primefaces

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces, spring-roo

I found [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jsf-20-spring-roo) cool post on DZone:

I wanted to give it a try. 
I followed the example step by step and it worked great for me. In less than 5 mins I had that web app described up and running.

I decided to create my own application just for fun. But it didn't work and I have not idea why it is. I am confident I did every thing in the exact same way but just using my own variable names. 
Here is every thing I did:

**1- From my linux terminal, created a folder and navigated to it**

```
mkdir whatsup
cd whatsup
```

**2- I started the roo shell to start working(my ROO_HOME is configured correctly)**

```
/roo.sh
```

> ---
>
> ```
>    / __ \/ __ \/ __ \ 
>   / /_/ / / / / / / / 
>  / _, _/ /_/ / /_/ /  
> /_/ |_|\____/\____/    1.2.1.RELEASE [rev 6eae723]
>
>
> Welcome to Spring Roo. For assistance press TAB or type "hint" then hit ENTER.
> ```

**3- I created the project definition**

```
roo> project --topLevelPackage com.hack --projectName whats-up
```

> ```
> Created ROOT/pom.xml
> Created SRC_MAIN_RESOURCES
> Created SRC_MAIN_RESOURCES/log4j.properties
> Created SPRING_CONFIG_ROOT
> Created SPRING_CONFIG_ROOT/applicationContext.xml
> ```

**4- I enabled the persistence layer**

```
roo> persistence setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY
```

> Created SPRING_CONFIG_ROOT/database.properties Updated
>   SPRING_CONFIG_ROOT/applicationContext.xml Created
>   SRC_MAIN_RESOURCES/META-INF/persistence.xml Updated ROOT/pom.xml
>   [added dependencies org.hsqldb:hsqldb:1.8.0.10,
>   org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.9.Final,
>   org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:3.6.9.Final,
>   org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final,
>   org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.2.0.Final,
>   javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA, cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2.2,
>   javax.transaction:jta:1.1,
>   org.springframework:spring-jdbc:${spring.version},
>   org.springframework:spring-orm:${spring.version},
>   commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.6, commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.3]

**5- I created my first entity**

```
roo> entity jpa --class ~.domain.Message
```

> Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/domain Created
>   SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/domain/Message.java Created
>   SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/domain/Message_Roo_Configurable.aj Created
>   SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/domain/Message_Roo_ToString.aj Created
>   SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/domain/Message_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj Created
>   SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/domain/Message_Roo_Jpa_Entity.aj

**6- I added the fields to the entity**

```
~.domain.Message roo> field number --fieldName votes --type java.lang.Integer --notNull
```

> Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/domain/Message.java Created
>   SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/domain/Message_Roo_JavaBean.aj

**7- Include the web layer to my project**

```
~.domain.Message roo> web jsf setup --implementation APACHE_MYFACES --theme PEPPER_GRINDER
```

> Created ROOT/src/main/webapp Created ROOT/src/main/webapp/index.html
>   Created ROOT/src/main/webapp/viewExpired.xhtml Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/resources/images Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/resources/images/csv.png
>   Created com.hack.jsf.converter.MessageConverter Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/resources/images/de.png Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/resources/images/en.png Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/resources/images/es.png Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/resources/images/excel.png Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/resources/images/favicon.ico Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/resources/images/pdf.png Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/resources/images/roo_logo.png Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/resources/images/springsource-logo.png Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/resources/images/xml.png Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/resources/css Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/resources/css/standard.css Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/resources/js Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/resources/js/calendar.js Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/templates Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/templates/content.xhtml Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/templates/footer.xhtml Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/templates/header.xhtml Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/templates/layout.xhtml Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/templates/menu.xhtml Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/pages Created
>   ROOT/src/main/webapp/pages/main.xhtml Updated ROOT/pom.xml [added
>   dependencies org.apache.myfaces.core:myfaces-api:2.1.5,
>   org.apache.myfaces.core:myfaces-impl:2.1.5,
>   org.primefaces:primefaces:3.1,
>   org.primefaces.themes:south-street:1.0.3,
>   org.springframework:spring-web:${spring.version}, javax.el:el-api:2.2,
>   commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.2.2,
>   commons-io:commons-io:2.1; added repository
>   http://repository.primefaces.org; added dependency
>   org.primefaces.themes:pepper-grinder:1.0.3; updated project type to
>   war] Created SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/WEB-INF Created
>   SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/WEB-INF/web.xml

**8- I performed a package**

```
~.domain.Message roo> web jsf all --package ~.jsf
```

> Created ROOT/src/main/resources/com/hack/jsf/i18n Created
>   ROOT/src/main/resources/com/hack/jsf/i18n/messages_de.properties
>   Created
>   ROOT/src/main/resources/com/hack/jsf/i18n/messages_en.properties
>   Created
>   ROOT/src/main/resources/com/hack/jsf/i18n/messages_es.properties
>   Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/jsf Created
>   SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/jsf/MessageBean.java Created
>   SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/jsf/converter Created
>   SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/jsf/converter/MessageConverter.java Created
>   SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml Created
>   SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/jsf/ApplicationBean.java Created
>   SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/jsf/util Created
>   SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/jsf/util/LocaleBean.java Created
>   SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/jsf/util/ViewExpiredExceptionExceptionHandlerFactory.java
>   Created
>   SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/jsf/util/ViewExpiredExceptionExceptionHandler.java Created SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/pages/message.xhtml Created
>   SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/jsf/ApplicationBean_Roo_ApplicationBean.aj
>   Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/jsf/ApplicationBean_Roo_Configurable.aj
>   Created
>   SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/jsf/converter/MessageConverter_Roo_Converter.aj
>   Created
>   SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/jsf/converter/MessageConverter_Roo_Configurable.aj Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/jsf/MessageBean_Roo_Serializable.aj
>   Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/jsf/MessageBean_Roo_Configurable.aj
>   Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/hack/jsf/MessageBean_Roo_ManagedBean.aj

**9- Exited the roo shell**

```
~.jsf roo> quit
```

**10- At the linux terminal, from inside the project I did run the command suggested in the tutorial to execute in tomcat 7**

```
~/hackday/whatsup$ mvn package org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:run -Dcargo.maven.containerId=tomcat7x -Dcargo.maven.containerUrl=http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.22/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.22.zip
```

This was the output when trying to run:

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building whats-up 0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Downloading:
>   http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/primefaces/themes/pepper-grinder/1.0.3/pepper-grinder-1.0.3.pom
>   Downloading:
>   http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/primefaces/themes/pepper-grinder/1.0.3/pepper-grinder-1.0.3.pom
>   Downloading:
>   http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/primefaces/themes/pepper-grinder/1.0.3/pepper-grinder-1.0.3.pom
>   Downloading:
>   http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release/org/primefaces/themes/pepper-grinder/1.0.3/pepper-grinder-1.0.3.pom
>   Downloading:
>   http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/pepper-grinder/1.0.3/pepper-grinder-1.0.3.pom
>   Downloaded:
>   http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/pepper-grinder/1.0.3/pepper-grinder-1.0.3.pom
>   (636 B at 3.3 KB/sec) Downloading:
>   http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/primefaces/themes/pepper-grinder/1.0.3/pepper-grinder-1.0.3.jar
>   Downloading:
>   http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/primefaces/themes/pepper-grinder/1.0.3/pepper-grinder-1.0.3.jar
>   Downloading:
>   http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/primefaces/themes/pepper-grinder/1.0.3/pepper-grinder-1.0.3.jar
>   Downloading:
>   http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release/org/primefaces/themes/pepper-grinder/1.0.3/pepper-grinder-1.0.3.jar
>   Downloading:
>   http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/pepper-grinder/1.0.3/pepper-grinder-1.0.3.jar
>   Downloaded:
>   http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/pepper-grinder/1.0.3/pepper-grinder-1.0.3.jar
>   (69 KB at 155.3 KB/sec) [INFO]  [INFO] ---
>   aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:compile (default) @ whats-up --- [ERROR] The
>   method findAllMessages() is undefined for the type Message [ERROR]
>   Type mismatch: cannot convert from Message to Message [ERROR] Type
>   mismatch: cannot convert from Message to Message [ERROR] The method
>   getId() is undefined for the type String [ERROR] The method merge() is
>   undefined for the type String [ERROR] The method persist() is
>   undefined for the type String [WARNING] advice defined in
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect has
>   not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch] [WARNING] advice defined in
>   org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl
>   has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch] [WARNING] advice
>   defined in
>   org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AbstractMethodMockingControl has
>   not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch] [WARNING] advice defined in
>   org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AbstractMethodMockingControl has
>   not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch] [WARNING] advice defined in
>   org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect
>   has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch] [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 15.525s [INFO] Finished at: Mon Jan 07 17:56:26 GMT
>   2013 [INFO] Final Memory: 6M/125M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:compile (default) on
>   project whats-up: Compiler errors : [ERROR] error at allMessages =
>   Message.findAllMessages(); [ERROR] ^^^^^^ [ERROR]
>   /home/cleanuser/hackday/whatsup/src/main/java/com/hack/jsf/MessageBean_Roo_ManagedBean.aj:72:0::0
>   The method findAllMessages() is undefined for the type Message [ERROR]
>   error at message = new Message(); [ERROR]  [ERROR]
>   /home/cleanuser/hackday/whatsup/src/main/java/com/hack/jsf/MessageBean_Roo_ManagedBean.aj:198:0::0
>   Type mismatch: cannot convert from Message to Message [ERROR] error at
>   message = new Message(); [ERROR] ^^^^ [ERROR]
>   /home/cleanuser/hackday/whatsup/src/main/java/com/hack/jsf/MessageBean_Roo_ManagedBean.aj:226:0::0
>   Type mismatch: cannot convert from Message to Message [ERROR] error at
>   if (message.getId() != null) { [ERROR]  [ERROR]
>   /home/cleanuser/hackday/whatsup/src/main/java/com/hack/jsf/MessageBean_Roo_ManagedBean.aj:233:0::0
>   The method getId() is undefined for the type String [ERROR] error at
>   message.merge(); [ERROR]  [ERROR]
>   /home/cleanuser/hackday/whatsup/src/main/java/com/hack/jsf/MessageBean_Roo_ManagedBean.aj:234:0::0
>   The method merge() is undefined for the type String [ERROR] error at
>   message.persist(); [ERROR]  [ERROR]
>   /home/cleanuser/hackday/whatsup/src/main/java/com/hack/jsf/MessageBean_Roo_ManagedBean.aj:237:0::0
>   The method persist() is undefined for the type String [ERROR] -> [Help
>   1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run
>   Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to
>   enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about
>   the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

I don't know how to make it work. 
As you can see my steps are exact the same as the DZone tutorial I don't know what is different. 
The interesting thing is that their example works but mine does'nt.

Also I tried without luck:
`mvn clean install` 
This will give me a BUILD SUCCESS but cannot make it run on the server
`mvn tomcat:run`
 Same result as with the other command

If there is somebody around with experience using `Spring Roo` in combination with `JSF`, I appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if "Message" clashes with some name used by the autogenerated code. Would you try it with, say, "MyMessage"?

Comment: That's right my I created that class with a different name and it worked fine. 
Thanks